# Custom domain in Tumblr

Tags: dns, tumblr, a-records

I setup this domain's A-record to point to this tumblr:

emmaraviv.com :: timeoftstretched.tumblr.com

Which works fine, but www.emmaraviv.com does not.

In tumblr, I have the "custom domain" set to "emmaraviv.com". I don't see a way to specify multiples. i.e. "emmaraviv.com", "www.emmaraviv.com".

I added another A-record for www., point to the same IP (the one Tumblr tells you to use). But when you try to go to this records address specifically (www.emmaraviv.com.ryan-orourke.com -- it's under my primary domain on my host) it resolves to Tumblr, but not her site. Which makes me think the issue is with Tumblr not recognizeing this domain as one that should be pointing at timeoftstretched.tumblr.com.

Would love some ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

On mine I did the following and it worked, on the DNS just setup:

```
@    A   66.6.44.4
www  A   66.6.44.4
```

Then both domain.com and www.domain.com both go to tumblr, in your Customize area just put www.domain.com as your domain, hopefully this should work.