# Tumblr redirect custom domain - WWW to non-WWW

Tags: tumblr

Tumblr's doc **'[Using a custom domain name](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains)'** is quite helpful it that it clearly states that I need to create an **A-record** for `example.com` pointing to `66.6.44.4`, so that my website is accessible via **example.com**.

But I don't understand this: **How do I make `www.example.com` take the user to `example.com`?**

It goes without saying that this needs to be done via DNS, in a Tumblr-compatible way (just in case there are any incompatibilities).

---

From searching, I read that it's NOT possible to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`. I can only hope this is NOT true.

If, unfortunately, it happens to be true, my only option is to create a CNAME record pointing `www.example.com` to `domains.tumblr.com` - isn't it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ah! As [stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5667868/1071413), you need to create two DNS entries as such:

- **A record:** pointing `example.com` to `66.6.44.4`
- **A record:** pointing `www.example.com` to `66.6.44.4`

I checked the domain in the answer - `emmaraviv.com` - apparently, `www.emmaraviv.com` redirects to `emmaraviv.com`. So yeah, this is it!

You need to create two records, an A record for the two-level domain (`example.com`) and another A record for the three-level domain (`www.example.com`), then add `example.com` in `Tumblr > Settings` for your blog, and now `example.com` should redirect to `www.example.com` without a hiccup — as far as I can see it.

**UPDATE:** Just tested this with my blog, and yes, I can confirm that it works!

Comment: @Tieme Sure! Had to wait 2 days to mark it, and then I forgot. :)

Comment: Wow, thanks. You'd be surprised how hard this is to find online.

Comment: is there any way to make both `example.com` **and** `www.example.com` available (no redirection)?

Comment: @MariusKavansky Tumblr does the redirection, so no. You can't have your tumblr blog available via both WWW and non-WWW domains.

Comment: According the the Tumblr's document, linked to in the question, you would need one A record, and one CNAME record. Not two A records.
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains

Comment: @alesch You can do it either way.

Comment: what about blog.example.com?